# images how to echo in table

Tags: php, echo

Hi how to echo in table i want  1 row 3 columns this is image gallery now all images listing vertical  i want to change in horizontal how can i change please help me to fix this issue

```
   echo '<div class="urbangreymenu">
    <ul><li><img src="wallpaper/' .$name . '/1.jpg" width="230" height="148" align="top"><a href="' .$path .'gallery.php?wallpapers=' .$name . '" >' . $name . '</a>'. $imgCount . 'Wallpapers</li></ul></div>';
      }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your needs, you want a table with 1 row and 3 columns;

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $path . '/' . $image1;?>"/>
</td>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $path . '/' . $image2;?>"/>
</td>
<td>
<img src="<?php echo $path . '/' . $image3;?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

set the img properties as you wish

Comment: what do you mean by auto echo table? there is no method to echo a table filled with all your needs as far as i know

Comment: also, use the comma sign, as we do not understand you 100%; comma = ,

Answer (score 0):

Set your style for li

```
.urbangreymenu > ul > li{
    float: left;
}
```

By default every new element which is not positioned fixed or absolute will be drawn beneath previous unless specified otherwise. [Learn More.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)